# const and let variable shadowing in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I have the following code. The only interesting part is that I redeclare `productId` in the second switch case.

```js
let productId = 1;

const check = true;

switch (check) {
  case false:
    console.log(productId);
    break;
  case true:
    let productId = 2;
    console.log(productId);
    break;
}
```

If I set `check` to `true`, then the code works correctly and prints

```
2
```

If I set `check` to `false`, then the code gives a `ReferenceError`

```
/home/osama/workspace/test/javascript.js:7
        console.log(productId);
                    ^

ReferenceError: productId is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/osama/workspace/test/javascript.js:7:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

If I use `var` to declare `productId` then the code works correctly regardless of the value of `check`.

I realize that the `let/const` statement is shadowing the global variable in someway, but my question is:

Why does the declaration of a variable inside a switch statement, cause the global variable to become undefined and throw a `ReferenceError`?

Comment: @Pointy happens when you change check to false

Comment: Temporal dead zone https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Another_example_of_temporal_dead_zone_combined_with_lexical_scoping

Comment: @CodeManiac yea I got it now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hoisting and Temporal Dead Zone!***

`let` and `const` get hoisted to the nearest block, so it becomes something like this:

```
switch (check) {
  let productId;
  case false:
    console.log(productId);
    break;
  case true:
    productId = 2;
    console.log(productId);
    break;
}
```

and thus because of `temporal dead zone`, the **ReferenceError** comes up

Comment: if `let` gets hoisted like you demonstrated, Then it shouldn't throw an error in fact it should print undefined

Comment: "All declarations (function, var, let, const and class) are hoisted in JavaScript, while the var declarations are initialized with undefined, but let and const declarations remain uninitialized."

Source: https://blog.bitsrc.io/hoisting-in-modern-javascript-let-const-and-var-b290405adfda

Comment: The case where `let` is uninitialized is when you try to access the variable before defining it `console.log(x);let x;` which is okay using `var`

Comment: Seems like, `hoisting` is defined as creating of variable in memory, so yes hoisted.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a `let` declaration in the `switch` block. Such declarations are kind-of "semi-hoisted".  They don't work like `var`, but the symbol `productId` inside the `switch` block is basically claimed by the declaration in the second `case`. Thus, the outer `productId` is shadowed.

If you wrap the code for the second case in `{ }`, it works fine.

```
switch (check) {
  case false:
    console.log(productId);
    break;
  case true: {
    let productId = 2;
    console.log(productId);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that it is 'semi-hoisted' but there must be some rule as to why or how this is happening.

Comment: @asamolion It's described as `Temporal Dead Zone`. link in comment below the question

Comment: @asamolion there certainly are rules. The `let` declaration in the `switch` block (the `{ }` for the whole `switch`) identifies `productId` as a variable local to the block. However, because it occurs in the second `case`, the code in the first `case` can't "see" it yet, because it comes after.

Comment: There important line to notice here `You may encounter errors in switch statements because there is only one block.`

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because you define the variable `productId` twice (before the switch statement and inside the second case)

```js
let productId = 1;

const check = true;

switch (check) {
  case false:
    console.log(productId);
    break;
  case true:
    productId = 2; // <-- remove the let keyword on this line, the var is already defined
    console.log(productId);
    break;
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's semantically different from the code in the question.

Comment: Indeed, this will overwrite the initial `productId` value. While scoping the second var won't. If this was not intended, I recommend using a different variable name though, at it leads to confusion (and many linters won't allow it).

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable prodctId before switch. Like this:

```
const check = true;
let productId;

switch(check) {
    case false:
        console.log(productId);
        break;
    case  true:
        productId = 2;
        console.log(productId);
        break;
}
```

Comment: This does work, but the meaning is different than the code in the question. (Well, what it would be if it were done properly.)

Comment: @Pointy Could you please explain your concern ? I did not get your point.

Comment: The code in the question creates a new variable in the scope of the `switch` statement. A change to that variable does not change the outer `productId`.  Now, I do not know what the OP *really* wants to do, so your change may be exactly right.